# Android Studio virtual device not working

Tags: macos, android-studio, macos-monterey

When I run the code in android, I just opens me a blank android device, without opening the app that I have written. I get the following errors in the build-
[image]

I am using macOS Monterey. Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273412/failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licences-have-not

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't check over there

Comment: Not a problem, I am glad it was of use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer that worked out for me is to install SDK command line tools as shown here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273412/failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licences-have-not.